# Dupehammer message is not styled correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The message that appears when hovering the tag badge on a dupehammer close is not styled correctly:

- missing the correct font
- not being restrained to a standard width
- not being positioned appropriately for the tag badge, causing flashing when moving the mouse over the overlap

[image]

Can this be rectified?

<sup>macOS Sierra 10.12

Safari Version 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10) or Safari Technology Preview Release 13 (Safari 10.0, WebKit 12603.1.5)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, now I've seen what a dupe hammer looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed today, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Discussed on Meta.SE at [Missing font on some error and dupehammer info popups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290979/222623).

[image]